# Boolean Functions

Tags: boolean-algebra

Say you have N input Boolean function, let's use a parity tree for the example. The function outputs a one or a zero depending on the values of the N inputs. Are the N inputs considered the preimage of the function?

Comment: @kelalaka; Thank you for replying, does that mean the answer to my question is "yes" , or is the answer "no" ?  ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Functions* don't have preimages; outputs do. Your Boolean function has *domain* the set of $2^N$ binary $N$-tuples, that is, the set
$$\big\{(000\ldots 00),~ (000\ldots 01),~ (000\ldots 10),~ (000\ldots 11),~ \cdots , (111\ldots 10),~ (111\ldots 11)\big\}$$ and *range* (a.k.a. the set of outputs) the set $\{0, 1\}$.  The *outputs* have *preimages* which are defined as the set of all inputs that are mapped onto that particular output by the specified function; in this instance the Exclusive-OR of the $N$ bits.  For example, with $N=3$,

- the *preimage* of $0$ is the set $\big\{(000),~ (011), ~ (101),~ (110)\big\}$
- the *preimage* of $1$ is the set $\big\{(001),~ (010), ~ (100),~ (111)\big\}$

Notice that the preimages are a *partition* of the domain; every element of the domain is necessarily a member of one (and only one) of the preimages.

In short, the answer to your question

> Are the N inputs considered the preimage of the function?

is  **No, they are not.**

Answer (score 0):

An $n(=N)$ input [Boolean function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_function) $f$ has $2^n$ input space, and output 0 or 1. Formally;

$$f:\{0,1\}^n \mapsto \{0,1\}$$

The [pre-image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)#Inverse_image) of $\{0,1\}$ under $f$ is the all input space $\{0,1\}^n$.

The pre-image of $0$ under $f$ is the set $$f^{-1}[0]=\{ x \in \{0,1\}^n |\; f(x) = 0\}$$

and the pre-image of $1$ under $f$ is the set $$f^{-1}[1]= \{ x \in \{0,1\}^n |\; f(x) = 1\}$$

And;

$$f^{-1}[0] \cup f^{-1}[1] = \{0,1\}^n $$

Don't confuse pre-image with the [inverse function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Injective,_surjective_and_bijective_functions).

Comment: I'm not a computer scientist. All your mathematical formulas make me dizzy! I'm looking for a "Boolean" answer to my question: Yes or NO. Merry Christmas by the way :-)

Comment: No, don't delete anything ! You can show future generations how really smart people cant answer simple questions sometimes !

Comment: A function must map all of its input space into the domain. But the function doesn't have to be onto. The pre-image is in your sense is the input space.